# Wedding guests for Gru and Lucy

Tags: despicable-me-2

I have watched the movie Despicable Me 2 and I am interested in the final scenes. A number of Gru's friends and enemies are at the wedding, including his neighbor and crazy date. Is there a list of the (non-minion) wedding guests who attended Gru and Lucy's wedding?

For a start I recognize the following: Silas Ramsbottom, the woman Gru went out with, the other woman with crazy teeth he met at the birthday party, Gru's neighbor, the waiter at the restaurant, Gru's mother, Dr Nefario.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, none documented. You can assume that they might be friends or coworkers of Lucy,other parents from the kids school, and maybe just maybe acquaintance of the scientist.

Comment: For a start I recognize the following: Silas Ramsbottom, the woman Gru went out with, the other woman with crazy teeth he met at the birthday party, Gru's neighbor, the waiter at the restaurant, Gru's mother, Dr Nefario. So quite a number of well known people are there.

Comment: You forgot the dog,and the minions

Comment: This really isn't a particularly helpful answer. Just because **you** didn't find any documented info doesn't mean it isn't out there.

Comment: @war_Hero: Ok I'll give you the dog, but I specified non-minion guests.

Comment: I know John but since the movie is all about the minions I just felt like adding